# Bind ngClass condition of element to it's parent div attribute

Tags: angular, binding, attributes, ng-class

I have such block in my html:

```
<div #eventOrderHead class="table__cell left clickable nowrap" [appSort]="events" data-order="desc" style="width: 1%;" data-name="order">
                            <span [ngClass]=" <bind to data-order> ? 'whis-sorting sorting-top' : 'whis-sorting sorting-bottom'">
                                №
                                <svg width="8" height="10" viewBox="0 0 8 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path class="bottom" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 6L4 10L8 6" fill="#9F9F9F" />
                                    <path class="top" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4L4 -4.29138e-07L0 4" fill="#9F9F9F" />
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

How can i bind in my ngClass condition to data-order property of div?

I tried simply write "eventOrderHead.data-order == 'asc'" but this caused error **"Can't bind to 'data-order' since it isn't a known property of 'div'"**.

Comment: did you try `eventOrderHead.dataset.order == 'asc'`?

Comment: Why not use `desc` directly in the `ngClass` condition: `[ngClass]="desc ? 'whis-sorting sorting-top' : 'whis-sorting sorting-bottom'"`?